# UIScrollView height vs. UIView height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

In my code I am increasing height of the `contentSize` of a `UIScrollView` when the UI orientation changes to landscape in order all views fit there and the user can scroll to see it.

In my XIB I have

```
/UIView - view
  |- UIScrollView - scrollView
       |- other subviews that should be scrollable
```

The scrollView has the same size as the view and its autoresize mask is set to resize in all directions.

I noticed that the scrollView's height dimensions are much greater than view's height.

E.g. I have some debug logs:

```
NSLog(@"%@ - self.view.frame=%@, self.view.bounds=%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
NSLog(@"self.scrollView.frame=%@, self.scrollView.bounds=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.bounds));
```

and it prints

```
willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: - self.view.frame={{0, 0}, {480, 219}}, self.view.bounds={{0, 0}, {480, 219}}
self.scrollView.frame={{0, 0}, {480, 399}}, self.scrollView.bounds={{0, 0}, {480, 399}}
```

And even in the Xcode IB it looks like:

[image: height of UIScrollView vs UIView]

Why doesn't the `UIScrollView` have same size as the view?

Thanks

---

**Update**

The strange thing is that when I set height of the scrollView to 460 (iPhone portrait), Xcode/IB show that the scrollView is smaller than its parent view (which also has set the same dimensions):
[image]

But now I have created a test project with 1 XIB that has only 1 `UIView`, added in there 1 `UIScrollView` and it looks normally, the `UIScrollView`'s height matches the `UIView`'s.

So perhaps I have somehow messed up the XIB and Xcode can't handle it well.

Anyway I am setting the dimensions programmatically (to handle rotations, UI composition changes etc.) and it works as expected. As it is my first iOS project, I was just wondering if there is any magic in `UIScrollView`. Apparently not :-)

Thanks for all your comments.

Comment: why don't you change the height of the scrollview to 460 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have created a test project with 1 XIB that has only 1 UIView, added in there 1 UIScrollView and it looks normally, the UIScrollView's height matches the UIView's.

So perhaps I have somehow messed up the XIB and Xcode can't handle it well.

Thanks for the comments you gave me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set the UIScrollView bounds to be 100% the same as its superview's. Next make sure that its superview has the autoresizesSubviews property set to YES. Then everything will work fine. Also "willAnimate..." means that the rotation operation has not yet been completed and you should check your new frames in the "didRotate" callback.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Eugene. The weird thing is that when I set the scrollView's height to 100% of the parent UIView (460px in this case), Xcode shows the scrollView just smaller (see the image I added to my question). I have updated my question and am going to close it: in another test project it looks OK. Probably some Xcode instability.